# Отключение/включение монитора по расписанию

Tags: экран

Чем можно программно отключать/включать монитор в WinXP по расписанию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, LPARAM(2));
```

Comment: Спасибо, но слишком хардкорно )

Comment: ну.. тогда http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272/ru

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

По пробуй Auto Shutdown Free

Comment: Нет функции отключения только монитора.